# importing array from row excel file to c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to import a row from excel sheet to C# like as array.
I can read the excel program and open excel sheet but I can’t apply the row to array.
Thanks for any one that help me….

```
Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook wb = ex.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\excel.xlsm");

Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.Sheets[1]; 

Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("B23", "E23");

System.Array arr = (System.Array)(range.Cells.Value2); 

// read it but not like array

 for (int ii = 0; ii < arr.Length; ii++)
         {
        Console.Write(arr[ii] + " ");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate your `System.Array` like so:

```
foreach (string a in arr)
{
    Console.Write(a);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Did it answer your question and/or was it useful?